# Default installation folder in advanced installer

Tags: installation, setup-project, advanced-installer

I wanna change default installation path in advanced installer v18.7, from C:\myApp to another volume like D:\myApp or E:\myApp and I used "Search", and set property to D:
it worked but it doesn't show D:\myApp (just show D:), and when target computer doesn't have  D:\ it shows E:\APPDIR

What should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **APPDIR** is the property attached to the **Application Folder** from the **Files and Folders** view. The default value can be set in the **Install Parameters** view:

[image]

I would recommend you to create a script file so that you can search when the installation starts for the available drive partitions, as not all computers may have the D:\ drive.

For example, you can use a PowerShell custom action to get the available drives, maybe filter based on their available free space. Then, you can set the APPDIR property with the drive letter that works best for you.

To set a property from a PowerShell Script custom action you can use the below cmdlet:

```
AI_SetMsiProperty APPPDIR "D:\New Path"
```

Comment: Hello, I used "Execute inline script code" and put it after "Searches" in "Install Execution Stage" but had no effect

Comment: Do you have a previous installation on the machine? By default, in Advanced Installer to old installation path is used during an upgrade. You can disable this setting in the Upgrades view.